# Visible spam/ad links in Joomla mobile site

Tags: javascript, joomla, spam

There is spam links in my joomla mobile website only found in the contact form page.

I have used an hour trying to find them within some of the template files without luck.

The links are following (from html source code):

```
<div id="b6q0jv">Play lots of fun games in our site to win the exciting <a     href="http://nvginc.org/online-casino-usa">online casino bonus</a>. 
<a href="http://www.nalato.com/beta1/?p=poker-texas-hold-em-online">hold'em poker</a> game can be    played from home. 
The <a href="http://www.cegp.org/?p=online-blackjack">blackjack games</a> and the live poker games     are almost the same way. 
You can play lots of casino games like online lottery and table games, after reading the <a href="http://www.nevsehir112.gov.tr/?p=mobile-casinos">www.nevsehir112.gov.tr/?p=mobile-casinos</a>.
```

My attempts:

1. Downloaded the whole folder and search for the keywords but no luck
2. Searched using Base64 encoding but still can't find it
3. Searched in the template folder of mobile template it isn't there

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the plugin "System - JCH Optimize" and the code disappear, although I couldn't find the injected script in the plugin folders at first.